# SQL update query with inner join: change to improve execution time

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have this query that, due to the number of records, is taking several hours and I wonder if there's a way to improve it:

```
update tableA target
inner join
    ( select b.columnZero, b.columnOne, b.columnTwo from tableB b
      inner join tableA a ON b.columnZero = a.columnZero
    ) as source
    on target.columnZero = source.columnZero
set
    target.columnOne = source.columnOne,
    target.columnTwo = source.columnTwo;
```

**Edit:** `columnZero` is primary key in `tableB` but not in `tableA`. In `tableA` I've got a different primary key from the columns mentioned above.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It'd be great to see the scheme - or at least to show which fields are indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are doing twice the same join (else I don't understand your query). What about:

```
update tableA a
inner join tableB b on a.columnZero = b.columnZero
set
    a.columnOne = b.columnOne,
    a.columnTwo = b.columnTwo;
```

Comment: that's it, thank you! (i've joined twice because in a different situation i had to group the results in the inner select, but here that doesn't apply)